# 「でしなに」とは、どういうこと？

Tags: translation, expressions

> フクスケが部屋をでしなにふりかえると、部長はかるく額に手を当てて眠りはじめた様子であった。

[日本三文オペラ　３１６頁](http://www.shinchosha.co.jp/book/112802/)（開高健著）

この小説に「でしなに」という表現が二、三度も出ますが、辞書を引いても出ててきません。

「出た途端」、あるいは「出て行く最中」などと推しますが、正確にどういう意味ですか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

辞書には「[出しな](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/151450/meaning/m0u/)」という形で載っています。「出かけようとする時。出ぎわ。出がけ」という意味です。

「でしなに」を分解すると、

> 「で」＋「しな」＋「に」

となります。「で」は、動詞の「出る」。「しな」は、[接尾語の「しな」](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/99279/meaning/m0u/)。「に」は助詞です。

ご参考までにですが、似たような用法の語では「[来しな](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/51728/meaning/m0u/)」も辞書で確認できます。

Comment: ご回答、ありがとうございます。ついでにですが、「でしなに」の発音はLHHLでしょうか。

Comment: @bright-star 私は標準語育ちですが、「出しなに」の発音は LHHH が自然に感じます。念のため、知人二名にも上の文を声に出して読んでもらいましたが、二人とも LHHH でした。文学の朗読として正しい発音かは分かりませんが、こちらでは LHHH で発音しています。